# jQuery - How to check if img src lacks filename?

Tags: jquery, image, replace, src

I have a `<img>`:

```
 <img src="http://example.com/mmm/01.jpg" class="test">
```

How can I check if the src is missing the `01.jpg` and replace it with some other image?

Basically

```
if (img src is 'http://example.com/mmm/') { 
    replace src with 'http://example.com/mmm/test.jpg'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var $img = jQuery("#myImg");
var src = $img.attr("src");

// if you have more image types, just add them to the regex. 
// I've used png and jpg as examples
if(!/\.(jpg|png)$/.test(src)) {

   var img = "test.jpg";

   // to see if the src url ends with / or not
   if(!/\/$/.test(src)) {
      img = "/" + img;
   }

   $img.attr("src", src + img);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution: [jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

This is the first hit not just on stack overflow, but on google as well...

Comment: +1.  In that post, this comment is the best solution in my opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images/#comments-168448

Answer (score 1):

You can check the last character in the src attribute to see if it's a '/' or not...

```
var img = $("img.test");
var src = $(img).attr("src");

if (src.lastIndexOf("/")+1 == src.length){
    $(img).attr("src",src+"test.jpg");
}
```

Comment: This may not always work. What if he doesn't have a trailing `/` and no image? Like `http://www.google.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check `$("img.test").attr("src")`

Answer (score 0):

`$(yourImg).attr("src")` will return you (or allow you to set) the url for the image as a string so you can then compare it with the values mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Can 'fix' many imgs at once (with the appropriate logic in the body)
$('img').attr('src',function(i,src){
  // If it's a JPG, leave it alone, otherwise...
  return /jpe?g$/.test(src) ? src : 'http://example.com/mmm/test.jpg';
});
```